# How Can I use '$' character in XML code?

Tags: xml, tags

How to use **$** symbol in xml file. I am facing little difficulties in that. Below is my xml schema

```
   <fieldname>ACCOUNT.NUMBER</fieldname>
   <fieldtype>NVARCHAR2</fieldtype>
   <fieldlength>30</fieldlength>
```

Kindly help me how to use **$** symbol in my xml schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $ in text, or in an attribute value, just use it directly. No escaping needed.

If you want to use $ in an element or attribute name, you're out of luck. You can't.

Answer (score -1):

Use it with:

```
<fieldexample><![CDATA[$$$$$]]></fieldexample>
```

For explanation of the use of CDATA, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784200/188331) explains it well.